# kdiff3 for Buster

Tags: raspbian-buster

The kdiff3 on Stretch worked okay, but the new version on Buster crashes, says it cannot scan files, etc and does not work for me.
Is there an alternative to kdiff3 for comparing large directory trees and seeing file content differences for Buster?

Comment: Have you looked at meld? This may also give you some idea of what is available https://alternativeto.net/software/kdiff3/.

Comment: Thanks; That was all I needed. I was disappointed to see Buster's kdiff3 version after using kdiff3 for years on multiple platforms. Some progress is not progress.

Answer (score 0):

Installation of both file/folder comparison programs worked fine with Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye version 11, using:

```
$ sudo apt install meld

$ sudo apt install kdiff*
```